# Variable in an array, is this possible? syntax error probably

Tags: php, arrays, variables, syntax

First I declare a variable that I want to use in multiple arrays through the code. This is a snippet of it where it should work, but it doesn't:

The variable:

```
$test = '<div id="test"> dit is een test </div>';
```

The array:

```
$sections[] = array( 
                'title' => $test, 
                'icon' => '/img/icons/home.png' 
                );
```

The title is always empty :-/

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you provide more of your script? The code you are providing should work.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. `$sections[0]['title']` should display it fine (assuming it's the first element in the array)

Comment: yes thats possible, did you try doing echo $sections[0]['title']; to get title ... that should give you the title

Comment: The code is fine. Likely the array declaration is in a place that cannot read `$test` (i.e. a scoping issue). Either way, we'll need to see more code.

Comment: did you var_dump($sections) to see values stored in your array??

Answer (score 1):

**Correct declaration is**

```
$test = '<div id="test"> dit is een test </div>'; 
$sections = array( 
                'title' => $test, 
                'icon' => '/img/icons/home.png' 
                );
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response everybody. In fact, tha code is a snippet from a wordpress framework. It is one menu item in the admin panel. The above code, doesn't work, I get an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxx/options.php" so it is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: I have found it, it was the first line of the code above that was the problem: $sections = array(); Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```
$test = '<div id="test"> dit is een test </div>';

$sections['title'] = $test;
$sections['icon'] = '/img/icons/home.png';

echo $sections['title'];
```